# tensorflow の tf になにか特別な意味がある？

Tags: python, tensorflow

タイトルについて、`numpy` を `np` とするような、"皆そうやっているからわかりやすいが、特に正当性はない略" に過ぎないと思っていたのですが、ドキュメントには [Module: tf](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf?hl=ja) 、 [tf.keras.Sequential](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/Sequential?hl=ja) などとあり、あたかも`tf`が正式名であるかのようです。
しかし実際は `import tensorflow as tf` としなければ、モジュール tf が見つからない、とエラーが出ます。
単に筆者が横着or勘違いしただけでしょうか、それともなにか tensorflow ではなく tf と書くべき特別な意味があるのでしょうか

---

追記
少し質問を変えてみます
`pip install hoge` した結果 `hg` というモジュールが使用可能になることはあり得ない、だからドキュメント中の `hg` は `hoge` の事だろう、という推測は可能ですか。

Comment: 何のドキュメントに基づいた話なんですか？
誤った情報が書かれているドキュメントなんて、掃いても掃いても無くせないほどありますけど、、、、

Comment: お疲れ様です。面白いご質問のような気がしました。tfとかに特別な意味はないと思いますが、、、なんか、習慣になっているんですかね、馴染んでます。2文字だとそれなりに表現できるものですね。nやtだと抵抗がありますが、npやtfは、今は、抵抗なしです。

Comment: APIドキュメントの各ページなんて巨大なライブラリのほんの一部分でしかなく、前提となるようなものは[チュートリアルとかで書いてる](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/quickstart/beginner)、という話のような気も……小規模なライブラリであったら1ページにすべてかかれている場合もありますし、でもそれじゃ不便な面もあるわけで。追記の内容については、Python初心者私は似たような雑な推測でドツボに嵌ったことがあるのでYesとは言えなさそうですが。

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Q. tf に意味がありますか？**

私の知る限り、特別な意味は無いです。単に慣習的なものです。その慣習と同じ語法を使ってドキュメントが書かれていても、特に不思議ではないです。TensorFlow の内部コードでも [tf や TF といった略称は使われています](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/search?q=tf&type=Code)し、勘違いと言うのは言い過ぎでしょう。

**Q. `tf` を import したいとき、その完全なパッケージ名を知る方法はありますか？**

ドキュメントを読んでください。TensorFlow のドキュメントではトップページに `pip install tensorflow` でインストールできるプロジェクトであると書かれていますし、チュートリアルに `import tensorflow as tf` と書かれています。

Python 一般の場合 [PEP 423](https://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0423/#use-a-single-name) で「プロジェクト名とパッケージ名は一緒にしてね」と決められているので、これが守られている限り `pip install XXX` が成功すると import できるようになるパッケージの名前は `XXX` です。一方で PEP 423 の注意書きにも書かれているとおり、歴史的経緯によりそうなっていないプロジェクトもあります。このためいつでも使える戦略としては「ドキュメントをちゃんと読む」「不安ならソースコードも読む」になるでしょう。

Comment: サンプルコードで使われている程度ならば「importを省略したのかな」で済みますが、「tf というモジュールがあります！」「Sequential の完全修飾名は tf.keras.Sequential です！」と言っているのでどういうことなんだろうかと思った次第です

Comment: ドキュメントは別に書き方のルールが決まっている訳ではないです。意図が伝わればそれで良い訳です。また、「Sequential の完全修飾名は tf.keras.Sequential です！」とまでは言ってないように見えます（行間を読みすぎではないでしょうか）。`import tensorflow as tf` した上では `tf.keras.Sequential` で参照できるクラスであることは間違いないのですし、僕は特に問題を感じないです。`import tensorflow as tf` については[チュートリアル](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials)に書いてありますし、PyPI に登録された名前が `tensorflow` であることは [Module: tf](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf?hl=ja) にも書かれています。

Comment: >PyPI に登録された名前が~ 質問の追記部分について解説していただくことは可能ですか？　別の質問に分けたほうが良いですか？

Comment: その部分、[XY問題](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2701/19110)かもなと思い、どう答えるか迷っていました。

Comment: Xとしてはkerasからtensorflow2.0に移行したいと思い、件のページを見て from tf.keras import Sequential と書いたらエラーになった、と言うものなんですが、from tensorflow. ... と書いて一応動くようにはなっています。疑問として残っているのは1. これで本当にあっているのか、2.どうすれば今後このようなミスをすぐに解決できるか、です。 1.に関してはこの記述はtensorflow1.0のものかもしれない、と注意しているのも理由です。>誤った情報が書かれているドキュメントなんて、掃いても掃いても無くせないほどあ るそうですし。ただ、反応を見る限りこの記述であっていそうです。2.に関して追記部分がYESならば良いのですが...

Comment: このimportのしかたであっていますか、という質問をすべきでしたかね？